# Trouble in detecting key presses in python using getch

Tags: python, getch

I'm new to python and I'm trying to make a console game. To detect key presses i'm using getch ( https://github.com/joeyespo/py-getch ). But when I press a the code starts repeating.

```
key = getch()
while (True):
    if (key == 'a'):
        principal.adicionaragua()
        principal.gastaragua()
        principal.aumentardias()
        principal.estado()
        time.sleep(2)
        clear()
```

**Edit**: I'm using windows and python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get `key` inside your loop. Otherwise, it will always be `'a'` since you do not check inside your loop.

```
while (True):
    key = getch()
    if (key == 'a'):
        principal.adicionaragua()
        principal.gastaragua()
        principal.aumentardias()
        principal.estado()
        time.sleep(2)
        clear()
```

Comment: Have a nice day :D !

Comment: Happy to help, have a nice day! :D